# How to apply the margin UI image to the end of screen as given in image, Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

Image on while playing game:

[image]

Image on editor:

[image]

As in the image in editor, I applied the UI image on end border of the canvas but Its not in border, while playing the game.

Final output something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to apply the UI image on border?
Or is there any other way to decorate the game over screen?

Comment: You should provide more details about your Query.

Comment: Do you move your `camera`? Your `canvas'` mode is set to `Screen Space - Camera`, so moving the `camera` will also move the `canvas`, which, obviously, will shift your image. Please, check it and if it's not the case, provide more details, as mentioned above.

Comment: Make sure the images are anchored correctly. [UI Basic Layout](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIBasicLayout.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.